Simultaneously optimize two functions with shared parameters to two different datasets
I have 2 functions that share a parameter, and I need to optimize these functions on two different datasets.
The first function is
eq_1_optim = function(ka,kel,t){return(0.004*(exp(-kel*t)-exp(-ka*t)))},
and I need to optimize it on (toy data set 1) t1=c(0,0.3,0.7,1,1.5,4,6), p1=c(0,2.5,4,4.4,3.8,2,0.9).
The second function is eq_2_optim = function(kel,t){return(0.004*(exp(-kel*t)))},
and I need to optimize it on (toy data set 2) t2=c(0.01,0.1,0.5,1,8), p2=c(0.5,0.4,0.01,0.01,0.004).
The parameter kel is present in both functions and should have the same optimized value after the optimization.
My approach is to add the residual sum of squares (RSS) as below. However, I am unsure if this is correct or if an established approach to my problem exists.
t=list(t1,t2)
observ = list(p1,p2)
obj_fun = function(par,t,observed){
t1=t[[1]]
t2=t[[2]]
observed_1 = observed[[1]]
observed_2 = observed[[2]]
predicted_model_1 = eq_1_optim(par[1],par[2],t1)
predicted_model_2 = eq_2_optim(par[2],t2)
rss1 = sum((observed_1-predicted_model_1)^2)
rss2 = sum((observed_2-predicted_model_2)^2)
return(rss1+rss2)
}
fit = optim(par=c(5,0.3),fn = obj_fun,t=t,observed=observ,method = "L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.5,0.01),upper=c(10,10))
Edit: These are definitely 2 different objective functions (rss1 and rss2) that must be solved simultaneously. Is optimizing this problem using the rmoo package possible? If so, how would I do it?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Since we only have 2 parameters use brute force to try a grid of 1000 points.
library(nls2)

DF <- data.frame(tt = c(t1, t2), pp = c(p1, p2),
  i = rep(1:0, c(length(t1), length(t2))))
 
fun <- function(ka, kel, t, i) 0.004*(exp(-kel*t) - i*exp(-ka*t))
st <- data.frame(ka = c(-10, 10), kel = c(-10, 10))
fm <- nls2(pp ~ fun(ka, kel, tt, i), DF, start = st,
  control = list(maxiter = 1000), alg = "brute")
fm

giving
Nonlinear regression model
  model: pp ~ fun(ka, kel, tt, i)
   data: DF
    ka    kel 
10.000 -0.323 
 residual sum-of-squares: 61

Number of iterations to convergence: 1024 
Achieved convergence tolerance: NA

We see that ka is driven to the maximum value in the grid so it looks like it wants to drive the second term to zero so we try again after dropping that term.  That can be done by setting i to 0.
fm2 <- nls(pp ~ fun(0, kel, tt, 0), DF, start = coef(fm)[2])
summary(fm2)

giving
Formula: pp ~ fun(0, kel, tt, 0)

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
kel   -0.556      0.833   -0.67     0.52

Residual standard error: 2.35 on 11 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.92e-06

kel is not significant and it seems that your model does not describe the data well.
You might be able to do slightly better by removing the first point as pp[1] = 0 and then taking the log of both sides.

Thanks for the proposed method. Regarding, "kel is not significant...", this is a toy dataset. However, I need to repeat the optimization on 200 real data pairs.

The functions I wrote above are essentially toy equations that, in real implementation, will be more complex (system of Ordinary Differential Equations). Is there a way to increase the speed of nsl2? Would another "alg" be faster? Also, how about parallelizing it?

Try fewer iterations.    Then use nls from the point found.  If you don't get a good answer try the different algorithms it supports.

I checked multiple posts that you posted on "StackOverflow", and mostly you use the "brute" algorithm. What is your opinion on using algorithms other than "brute"? In some cases, the fitted parameters with "brute") are in lower or upper limits; however, with a "random" algorithm, they get other values.

brute gives a grid so if it is driven to the boundary then it is an indication that that parameter may be driven to Inf or -Inf.  With random the points will all be in the interior so its harder to tell.  If brute does not give a boundary point you can try random to see if by chance you get a better starting value for the subsequent use of nls.  If you do you random be sure to use set.seed first so it can be reproduced.
